# Long Query String Being Split

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, navigation, query-string, windows-phone

I'm using the query string to pass data between two PhoneApplicationPages but the destination page is recieving the data as multiple paameters instead of one big string. This is a problem as I'm passing data as JSON which cannot be desrialized if it's truncated mid flow.

The data I'm passing is:

```
NavigationService.Navigate("/MainPage.xaml?view=recipes&searchargs={"Author":null,"AuthorFilterType":2,"Categories":["1 Point","100-200 Calorie","1-3 grams Fat","3 Point","Baked Snack","Bakery & Baked Products","Banana","Beer","Boutique Wines","Bread","Breakfast","Breakfast Drinks","Cake","Cakes","Cocktails","Collectible Wines","Cookie","Cookie Dessert","Dairy","Dessert","Desserts","Diabetic","Drinks & Beverages","Fruit","Fruit Dessert","Fruit Drinks","Fruits","Gluten Free","High Fiber","Main Course","Main dish","Pasta","Pork","Raw Foods","Salads","Sandwiches","Shake & Smoothie","Side dish","Snack","Strawberry","Sweet Snack","Under 1 gram Fat","Under 100 Calorie","Vegetarian","Weight Watchers Points","Yogurt"],"Countries":[],"GlobalSearch":"","Ingredients":[],"MaxIngredients":0,"MinIngredients":0,"Name":null,"NameFilterType":2,"Rating":0,"Types":[]}");
```

But the query string contains this:

[image: Split query string]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the " used by json try this

```
NavigationService.Navigate("/MainPage.xaml?view=recipes&searchargs={\"Author\":null,\"AuthorFilterType\":2,\"Categories\":[\"1 Point\",\"100-200 Calorie\",\"1-3 grams Fat\",\"3 Point\",\"Baked Snack\",\"Bakery & Baked Products\",\"Banana\",\"Beer\",\"Boutique Wines\",\"Bread\",\"Breakfast\",\"Breakfast Drinks\",\"Cake\",\"Cakes\",\"Cocktails\",\"Collectible Wines\",\"Cookie\",\"Cookie Dessert\",\"Dairy\",\"Dessert\",\"Desserts\",\"Diabetic\",\"Drinks & Beverages\",\"Fruit\",\"Fruit Dessert\",\"Fruit Drinks\",\"Fruits\",\"Gluten Free\",\"High Fiber\",\"Main Course\",\"Main dish\",\"Pasta\",\"Pork\",\"Raw Foods\",\"Salads\",\"Sandwiches\",\"Shake & Smoothie\",\"Side dish\",\"Snack\",\"Strawberry\",\"Sweet Snack\",\"Under 1 gram Fat\",\"Under 100 Calorie\",\"Vegetarian\",\"Weight Watchers Points\",\"Yogurt\"],\"Countries\":[],\"GlobalSearch\":\"\",\"Ingredients\":[],\"MaxIngredients\":0,\"MinIngredients\":0,\"Name\":null,\"NameFilterType\":2,\"Rating\":0,\"Types\":[]}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Hermit Dave. For reference, the methods are `Uri.EscapeDataString()` and `Uri.UnescapeDataString()`.